# customized facebook share button

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I need to make a customized share button, where I can programmatically modify all the components of the share, such as the title, description, and sharing image.

I have tried just the og meta tags, but they haven't made a difference. I tried adding data-image etc. tags to the HTML link element, and that didn't fix it either. I also tried using the JS SDK, where I create a postToFeed() function with the data.

Am I doing something wrong? Are these outdated methods? Is this not the expected use case for the SDK share functions?

Comment: always add your code on stackoverflow, so we can answer more specific. in order to tell you if something is outdated, you need to tell us what methods you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh the Open Graph data for an URL in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

That tool is very important to test your OG tags too, of course.

You can also use the feed dialog and specify your own data: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

Although, i would recommend using OG tags with the share dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much for this!